# How can I move code snippet in View class to OnAppearing() method?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, methods, mvvm

I'm trying to bind the properties of the views in the view page to a class I have in a carpet called ViewModel and then access the properties from an instance of another class called Category (a model) in a carpet called Model. The problem is that it doesn't seem to work. Although there are no error codes in the .codes, I cannot access the bindings when I run the application. The warning I get is: Datacontext not found for SelectedCategory .CategoryName binding. I want to try OnAppearing method to solve this problem but I have no idea how to do it. According to my research I need to move the following piece of code to OnAppearing method but I couldn't.
`cvm = new CategoryViewModel(category); this.BindingContext=cvm` I want to move these code snippets to OnAppearing method.Do you have any  suggestions? Thank You!!

**1.CategoryViewModel.cs**

```
public class CategoryViewModel:BaseViewModel
{

    private   Category _SelectedCategory;
    public Category SelectedCategory
    {
        set
        {
            _SelectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get
        {
            return _SelectedCategory;
        }
    }




    public ObservableCollection<ProductItem> ProductItemsByCategory { get; set; }

   private  int _TotalProductItems;
    public int TotalProductItems
    {
        set
        {
            this._TotalProductItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get
        {
            return this._TotalProductItems;
        }
    }

    public CategoryViewModel( Category category)
    {
        SelectedCategory = category;
  

        ProductItemsByCategory = new ObservableCollection<ProductItem>();
     

        GetProductItems(category.CategoryID);

    }

     async void GetProductItems(int categoryID)
    {
        var data = await new ProductItemService().GetProductItemsByCategoryAsync(categoryID);

        ProductItemsByCategory.Clear();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            ProductItemsByCategory.Add(item);
        }
        TotalProductItems = ProductItemsByCategory.Count;
    }
    
}
```

**2.CategoryView.cs**

```
 CategoryViewModel cvm;

    public CategoryView(Category category )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cvm = new CategoryViewModel(category);
        this.BindingContext=cvm
       
        

           ;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var bindingContext = BindingContext as CategoryViewModel;
        if (bindingContext != null) { }
            
    }

    async void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();



    }

    async void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedProduct = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as ProductItem;
        if (selectedProduct == null)
            return;
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ProductsDetailsView(selectedProduct));
        ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

    }
}
```

**3.BaseViewModel.cs**

```
public  class BaseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

  
}
```

Comment: it's completely unclear what problem you are trying to solve.  You appear to be having trouble with bindings, but you haven't posted any XAML demonstrating what bindings you're trying to make work.

Comment: No need for "OnAppearing", post your xaml code.

Answer (score 0):

To move the code into `OnAppearing` method , you can create a `Category`  varibale to assign the value in class constructor ,and use it in `OnAppearing` method.

```
Category _category ;
CategoryViewModel cvm {get;set;}

public CategoryView(Category category )
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _category  = category;    
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    cvm = new CategoryViewModel(_category);
    this.BindingContext=cvm;
}
```